# Creating a popup list view on the iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, dialog

I'm developing an app and I want to have a popup list view similar to the one in Safari on iOS:

[image]

This kind of popup with the little speech bubble style arrow and a thin border appears on a number of apps. Is it a standard component? If so how can I create one?

Comment: Is this for iPad? The [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is exclusive to iPad (not available on iPhone).

Comment: The question is similar but I was specifically looking for the default implementation for the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called UIPopoverController.

You create it with it's designated initializer

```
– initWithContentViewController:
```

I strongly recommend you to [read its docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for I just wasn't sure what it was called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for the iPad, use a UIPopoverController. However, popovers are not supported on the iPhone natively. Instead of using the popover on the iphone, I would created a new scene that contains what you wanted int your popover.

However, if you are committed to using a popover on the iPhone, there are a variety of third party APIs that you can take a look at. WEPopover is one of the more popular ones.